# How to compress asp.net page in code level?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, gzip

I added a method called Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute in global.ascx like this:

```
void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string cTheFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Path;
    string sExtentionOfThisFile = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(cTheFile);

    if (sExtentionOfThisFile.Equals(".aspx", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        HttpApplication httpApp = (HttpApplication)sender;

        string acceptEncoding = httpApp.Request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(acceptEncoding))
        {
            return;
        }
        acceptEncoding = acceptEncoding.ToLower();

        System.IO.Stream requestStream = httpApp.Response.Filter;

        if (acceptEncoding.Contains("gzip"))
        {
            httpApp.Response.Filter = new System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(requestStream,
                System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Compress);
            httpApp.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
        }
        else if (acceptEncoding.Contains("deflate"))
        {
            httpApp.Response.Filter = new System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream(requestStream,
                System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Compress);
            httpApp.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Encoding", "deflate");
        }
    }

}
```

It worked when browse normal page.

but if a page contains UPDATE-PANEL error will happen.
I get a PageRequestParserException. 
when update-panel async post back, this error happens.

any idea?

Comment: @SanjayGoswami              PageRequestParserException

Comment: @SanjayGoswami  PageRequestParserException  It happens when update panel post back request

Comment: @Kevin Are you sure that is the compression and not other error ?

Comment: @Aristos
 details:error parsing near "82&ModeType=Verifica"    full url is :  http://127.0.0.1/displaydatabase/shared/UpdateTestReport.aspx?TemplateNumber=6082&ModeType=Verification

Comment: @Kevin Ok, where this error is appear. Do that. 1.remove the update panel to see if the error still exist.

Comment: @Aristos i don't know the update panel works good before, I try to add some code to compress my site, the error happend

Comment: @Aristos other pages without update panel are fine, they're all compressed, but pages with update panel when this kind of page post back request a message box will show

Comment: @Kevin The next think that you need to check is if you set the content length somewhere. (some times new bugs come up - this is not mean that this compression is the reason). Also check if iis make a second compression that both of them breaks up.

Comment: @ Aristos I tried on a simple webForm app, If i change the project's 'target framework' to .net2.0, this error will happen. but IF i put these compress codes to page's constructor, and the framework version is 3.5, it will work fine.

Comment: @ Aristos I 'fixed' this error by set  EnableEventValidation="false" ... seems this option not good for my code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "fixed" by set the EnableEventValidation to false on my page and move compress logic to page's constructor.
Obviously this is not a good solution(close validation).
If anybody know a good solution, pls let me know.

and found that if the project's framework version is 3.5, all works fine,
but if the version is 2.0. this error will happen.